# Tfs work item of type test case creation using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to create a work item of type test case in TFS using c# in visual studio. I am able to set the values of all fields except the field "steps". How to set the step field's value?

I tried `workitem.Fields["steps"].value = "value"` but is not working.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How did you specify the "value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That`s not working because you have to use reference to TestManagement Client. Then get your test case and add new steps like this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs;

tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(uri)); 
tfs.Authenticate();

ITestManagementService service = (ITestManagementService)tfs.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
ITestManagementTeamProject testProject = service.GetTeamProject(project);    

ITestCase testCase = TestProject.TestCases.Find(1);
ITestStep newStep = testCase.CreateTestStep();
newStep.Title = "New Step Title";
newStep.ExpectedResult = "New Step Expected Result";
testCase.Actions.Add(newStep);
```

Look these links:

1. [Programmatically Create Test Case Steps](https://www.pmichaels.net/2016/12/07/programmatically-create-test-case-steps/)
2. [TFS API Part 51 – Adding Test Step & Shared Step](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2013/10/07/tfs-api-part-51-adding-test-step-amp-shared-step/)

Answer (score 0):

Please notice the `Steps` field is `html` type. You could try to use REST API to set steps' value. An example is as below:

```
POST https://xxxx.visualstudio.com/{teamproject}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Test%20Case?api-version=4.1

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample testcase"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps",
    "from": null,
    "value": "<steps id=\"0\" last=\"3\"><step id=\"2\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;step1&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;0&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description/></step><step id=\"3\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;step2&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;pass&lt;/P&gt;</parameterizedString><description/></step></steps>"
  }
]
```